# uninstall applications using a button click in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application, I've developed to get a list of third party applications that the user installed. from that, what now I want is to add a button where, when clicked the user is directed to the inbuilt application details screen with the force stop and uninstall option, since I only take user installed application I don't need root permission and as well as system permission. is there a way to call that system intent inside my application.

Answer (score 1):

try as:

```
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent();
    detailsIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
    "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");

    //ApiLevel greater than or equal to 8
    detailsIntent.putExtra("pkg", "Appliction_Package_NAme");

    //ApiLevel in less than 8

    detailsIntent.putExtra("com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName", 
    "Appliction_Package_NAme");

    startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:app package name"));
   startActivity(intent);
```